# Outlook 2010 removes + from mobile numbers

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

i want to organize my business contacts in Outlook 2010(on Windows 7 Professional) and then synchronize them with my HTC Sensation. But when i enter mobile phone number in format +421900000000(+421 is international prefix for Slovakia) Outlook removes +(plus) sign from beginning of number(i need this format for my HTC).
How can i set up Outlook to not remove + from numbers?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Outlook does not remove pluses if you have your Windows' **Dialing Rules** setup correctly. Make sure you have your area code entered in Windows' Dialing Rules (**Phone and Modem** in the **Control Panel**).

Comment: mega thx thims, thats works superbly and you saved me from long editing ;-)

Comment: But, this doesn't support using + in the "If you dial a number to access an outside line, what is it?" field. I know 00 is an alternative, but really, afaik + is *the* standard for this. I've also heard that some smart-phones doesn't actually even support 00.

Comment: This does not seem to work in areas without area codes. But it actually does. Just going there once solved the problem from me. I can now import contacts from the company address book and the plus signs will not be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

What also works is just entering the data in their format, so "+xx", space, "(xxx)", space, "xxxxxxx". Just in case you can't find the modem settings like me or do not want to change them.

Comment: In whose format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use space between area code and main number,
for example Outlook converts "+77771234567" in this format "77771234567" in fact deletes + in the beginning.

If you will change it to this format "+7 7771234567" Outlook will understood that +7 is area code and will leave it as is. 
e.g. if you have database with list of numbers you can easily edit them all.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem.  The solution is somewhat unintuitive and US-style...but it works.
In the Windows Dialing Rules just insert the area code of your location (20 in case of London) and save.

I found that when entering the telephone number in the Contacts list the plus sign is not removed.  Don't be put off by the fact that the city area code is suddenly enclosed in brackets, e.g. +421 (90) 000000, taking the number of the initial post as an example.  Entering directly in that format as suggested by another contributor here also worked.

How this works when I have sync'ed to my (Windows) phone and I try to dial the number I shall find out in a few months' time when I migrate out of Windows Live Mail (where there is no such problem with phone numbers).

As regards the 'prefix for an outside line' question somebody asked, that refers to a code needed to get out of a shared line/hotel/office environment and precedes (sometimes with a short pause) any country code (00, 011, 001...) or city area code. The plus sign was introduced to bypass the varying country-code prefixes but does not (yet?) work on fixed-line phones using traditional technology.